# how to make the textfiled clear on click

Tags: ipad, uitextfield

i have app i want that when user enters any data and text field has by default 10 so when user click on textfield then it clear the textfield to enter data.It mean when user enters data it doest not delete one bye one like clear 1 and o with back space but by default when user click textfield it should get clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Apple Developers* already did this for you, set the `10` into `UITextField` placeholder property [see doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006888-CH3-SW14), when you tap on the textfield, it will be remove *automatically*!

However, if you want to clear it in case you've added `10` as text of textfield then,

```
 - (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField 
 {
       textField.text = @"";
 }
```

It will call each time when you focus to textfield.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField  
 {  
       [textfield settext:@""];
 }
```

if you focus on textfield then this method is called and textfield is cleared.